# cswp on a blog: how to display the categories

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, content-search-web-part

Sharepoint on line. I am struggling with standard content search web part and displaying the categories line. I have used a refinablestring and mapped to ows_postcategory. Nothing is showing up.

Comment: it usually takes 24 hours, but to speed it up, you can reindex the site collection from `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx`. The mapping looks correct, but it takes time to get populated

Comment: ok, now it works, just out of my curiosity, in this case was it better to go as I did or to create a new managed property (text) and map it to ows_postcategory? what is the difference between the 2 ways?

Comment: You took the correct approach to map crawled property to `RefinableStringxx` . In case of creation of new custom managed property, we only have text or yes/no option and you cant make it refinable in SPO.